# Update Multiple UpdatePanels using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to update multiple panels

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <!-- Stuff -->
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Always" OnLoad="UpdatePanel2_Load">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <!-- Different stuff -->
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Always" OnLoad="UpdatePanel3_Load"> 
<ContentTemplate>
 <!-- Different stuff --> 
</ContentTemplate> </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And I triggered it in javascript

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            //$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BoxContent_Button1").click();           
            __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', 'Update-Both');
        });
    </script>
```

And the Backend code is

```
protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["__eventargument"] == "Update-Both")
            {

                //update stuff;    

            }            

        }

        protected void UpdatePanel2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["__eventargument"] == "Update-Both")
            {
                //update stuff

            }

        }

        protected void UpdatePanel3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["__eventargument"] == "Update-Both")
            {
                //update stuff
            }
        }
```

I found the control can be updated, however, the codes run keep looping to UpdatePanel1_Load ,UpdatePanel2_Load,UpdatePanel3_Load again and again. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is that the __dopostback cause the loop. If so, how can I just trigger to update update panel just once.

Comment: Why trigger an UpdatePanel update immediately when the page is done loading?

Comment: That's the same question like yesterday just slightly modified. If it's on load why not putting it into the Page_Load?

Comment: Because the function takes long time to load. If put it in page load. The page will be in loading for long time